# How can I subscribe to a Nest camera for live events?

Tags: node.js, api, nest-api

I've seen the following snippet in the Nest documentation implying that this is possible:

"Your products can read and write sections of the JSON document, and can also subscribe to changes in sections of the document. This subscription capability allows your products to react in real time to changes made to the system, like turning lights off when a user sets the structure to away."

How do I subscribe my application to these sections and as soon as an event gets triggered get a callback notification so I can capture the event as soon as it happens?

Thanks in advance for helping out!